# Razor Service Stack on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, servicestack, azure-storage

I'm liking a lot what I see about Service Stack, and want to use it with Azure. I found the following project and it compiles ok, but there is either something not mentioned in the readme documents or the 2.1 vs. 2.0 version of the Azure Emulation services is not compatible (which seems unlikely)

I probably have to setup the store manually, but I don't see any interfaces in the emulator to do that.

https://github.com/letsbootstrap/Razor.ServiceStack-On-Azure

```
Message=Login failed for user 'RazorServiceStack'.
```